# check if email/password are correct before redirection using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I need to make a redirection to another page (component) when user validates successfully with email/password, otherwise, show a warning message on a div that says email or password not correct.

This is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        // name: "",
        cnx_mail: '',
        cnx_pwd: '',
        joinByEmail: '',
        items: [],
        token: '',
        redirectToReferrer: false,
        errors: {},

        formErrors: {
            cnx_mail: '',
            cnx_pwd: ''
        },
        emailValid: false,
        passwordValid: false,
        formValid: false
    }
    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(`${API}/api/connexion`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.cnx_mail,
                password: this.state.cnx_pwd,
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            localStorage.setItem('toktok', json.result);
            //i have to verify email/password bedore redirection
            window.location.href = "/accounts";
        });
}
```

And this is my form in render():

```
<form className="demoForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate
    encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div className="alreadysubscribed-input">
        <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input
            ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_mail)}`}>
            <input type="email" required
                className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_mail"
                value={this.state.cnx_mail} id="cnx_mail"
                onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_mail} />
            <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_mail">Email</label>
            <div className="fatb-bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input
            ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_pwd)}`}>
            <input type="password" required
                className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_pwd"
                value={this.state.cnx_pwd} id="cnx_pwd"
                onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_pwd} />
            <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_pwd">Mot de passe</label>
            <div className="fatb-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <FormErrors formErrors={this.state.formErrors} />

    <div className="btn-cnx">
        {/* <span className="mas">Se connecter</span> */}
        <button className="fatb-btn bubbly-button btn-anim3 w100p" type="submit"
            name="cnx_btn" disabled={!this.state.formValid}>se
            connecter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

i need to verify if the role == "admin" then redirect to /accounts or  redirect to /account if its role=="user", otherwise display a warning msg in a div for example.

this is the structure of my data :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "result": [
        {
            "dateCreation": "2019-10-09T21:54:18.491Z",
            "resetpasswordtoken": null,
            "resetpasswordexpires": null,
            "role": "admin",
            "enable": true,
            "_id": "5d9e67772682971c1fc3711c",
            "email": "meachemlal@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$HqEMSkaWBZ..BFvSpxliUu/02vWodvxYoFZMaYUU5ZsBeqeZB4jLu",
            "tickets": [],
            "gains": [],
            "__v": 0,
            "nom": "ACHEMLAL",
            "prenom": "MERYEM",
            "tel": "+33619562721"
        },
        {
            "dateCreation": "2019-10-09T21:54:18.491Z",
            "resetpasswordtoken": null,
            "resetpasswordexpires": null,
            "role": "admin",
            "enable": true,
            "_id": "5d9e677e2682971c1fc3711d",
            "email": "mika.achemlal@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$Bg4nOrNMzc.b/JBNKNiRP.BiMd/.h4CHKiy0nvV/uim0d3VwHl9iq",
            "tickets": [],
            "gains": [],
            "__v": 0
        },
    ........
```

THANK YOU

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: checking if email and password are good and role == "admin" then redirect to /api/accounts, otherwise redirect to /api/account if email and password are good  and role =="user".
thanks